# Flink: how to write null values as empty through writeAsCsv in sink

Tags: java, csv, apache-flink

I have my a pojo which I create on runtime and there could be null values in the pojo object. When I try to write the object values in a CSV file with `dataset.writeAsCsv`, the following exception appears:

```
org.apache.flink.types.NullFieldException: Field 0 is null, but expected to hold a value.
```

In this case my integer is null. but same is the case with Date.

Is there any way to write null values as empty back to CSV output file?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only call the `writeAsCsv`method on [Datasets of Tuples](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/DataSet.html#writeAsCsv-java.lang.String-), there must be a place in your code where your `Dataset<Pojo>` is transformed into a `Dataset<TupleN>`.

Tuples can hold `null` values, but are [not serializable](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6115) when holding them. (The [javadoc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/tuple/Tuple.html) more or less warns about this.) If you look at the surrounding lines of your exception you may find that it is thrown at serialization, at least this is what I could reproduce:

```
org.apache.flink.types.NullFieldException: Field 1 is null, but expected to hold a value.
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.TupleSerializer.serialize
```

So I guess you will have to determine what a null value means in the domain of your POJO and replace it accordingly before you write your CSV file. A solution *could* be to transform your values to `String`s and replace `null` with `""`. However, depending on the *meaning* of the value other substitutions could be more appropriate.